# How does one format a number with commas?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch 2, how does one format a number with commas with either 0 or 2 decimal places?  I imagine that there's a built in way to do this?

For example, I have 1234.567 and I need the number as 1,234 and 1,234.57.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with JavaScript only :
**Add commas to the number**

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
nStr += '';
x = nStr.split('.');
x1 = x[0];
x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
}
return x1 + x2;
}
```

**Round to the nearest integer**

```
var result = Math.round(original)
```

**Round to two decimals**

```
var result = Math.round(original*100)/100
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this function from Ext JS 4's `Ext.util.Format`, which is not part of the Sencha Touch 2 API. Just implement it in your application and you're set.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Format.html#Ext-util-Format-method-number

Answer (score 0):

```
function iFormatValueTwoDecimals(inValue)
{
    var leftSide  = Math.floor(inValue);
    var rightSide = Math.round((inValue - leftSide)*100);

    if(rightSide === 0)
    {
        rightSide = '00';
    }
    else if(rightSide < 10)
    {
        rightSide = rightSide + '0';
    }

    return  leftSide+'.'+rightSide;
}
```

Comment: Simpler ... ;)

`code var result = parseFloat(original).toFixed(2);`